# Count number of subsequences with given k modulo sum

Tags: algorithm

Given an array `a` of `n` integers, count how many subsequences (non-consecutive as well) have `sum % k = 0`:

```
1 <= k < 100
1 <= n <= 10^6
1 <= a[i] <= 1000
```

An `O(n^2)` solution is easily possible, however a faster way `O(n log n)` or `O(n)` is needed.

Comment: non consecutive? subsequences?

Comment: Since you specified constant upper bounds any solution to your problem is trivially O(1).

Comment: haha :) that is good !! @JohnColeman

Comment: u sure its `subsequence` and not `subarray`?

Comment: @vish4071 my comment was partially a joke but also partially serious. If the bounds are all fixed then it isn't a problem involving asymptotic complexity at all but if all bounds are lifted then determining if the count is > 0 seems NP-complete in view of its connection to subset-sum. OP needs to clarify which bounds are part of the problem statement.

Comment: @JohnColeman this is probably some online judge problem. They tell you the upper bounds and a time limit to give you an idea about what complexity your solution should have in order to run in that time limit for the given upper bounds.

Comment: @JohnColeman, I know what you meant. Of course if you know every upper bound, your solution will always be O(1). But that's the theoretical aspect of definition of complexity that I don't like, as this is why this concept fails to analyse real time situations. Of course this problem is on some coding platform and he has time limit which won't allow a solution to pass if it has O(max n^2) operations. And he wants that optimized.

Comment: @JohColeman haha nice.. :D

Comment: @vish4071 yeah i am sure it is subsequence and not subarray

Answer (score 3):

This is the [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem.

A simple solution is this:

```
s = 0
dp[x] = how many subsequences we can build with sum x 
dp[0] = 1, 0 elsewhere
for i = 1 to n:
    s += a[i]
    for j = s down to a[i]:
        dp[j] = dp[j] + dp[j - a[i]]
```

Then you can simply return the sum of all `dp[x]` such that `x % k == 0`. This has a high complexity though: about `O(n*S)`, where `S` is the sum of all of your elements. The `dp` array must also have size `S`, which you probably can't even afford to declare for your constraints.

A better solution is to not iterate over sums larger than or equal to `k` in the first place. To do this, we will use 2 `dp` arrays:

```
dp1, dp2 = arrays of size k
dp1[0] = dp2[0] = 1, 0 elsewhere
for i = 1 to n:
    mod_elem = a[i] % k
    for j = 0 to k - 1:
        dp2[j] = dp2[j] + dp1[(j - mod_elem + k) % k]

    copy dp2 into dp1

return dp1[0]
```

Whose complexity is `O(n*k)`, and is optimal for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's an `O(n + k^2 lg n)`-time algorithm. Compute a histogram `c(0), c(1), ..., c(k-1)` of the input array mod `k` (i.e., there are `c(r)` elements that are `r` mod `k`). Then compute

```
  k-1
product (1 + x^r)^c(r) mod (1 - x^k)
  r=0
```

as follows, where the constant term of the reduced polynomial is the answer.

Rather than evaluate each factor with a fast exponentiation method and then multiply, we turn things inside out. If all `c(r)` are zero, then the answer is `1`. Otherwise, recursively evaluate

```
      k-1
P = product (1 + x^r)^(floor(c(r)/2)) mod (1 - x^k).
      r=0
```

and then compute

```
      k-1
Q = product (1 + x^r)^(c(r) - 2 floor(c(r)/2)) mod (1 - x^k),
      r=0
```

in time `O(k^2)` for the latter computation by exploiting the sparsity of the factors. The result is `P^2 Q mod (1 - x^k)`, computed in time `O(k^2)` via naive convolution.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse `a` and count `a[i] mod k`; there ought to be `k` such counts.

Recurse and memoize over the distinct partitions of `k, 2*k, 3*k...etc.` with parts less than or equal to `k`, adding the products of the appropriate counts.

For example, if `k` were `10`, some of the partitions would be `1+2+7` and `1+2+3+4`; but while memoizing, we would only need to calculate once how many pairs mod `k` in the array produce `(1 + 2)`.

For example, `k = 5, a = {1,4,2,3,5,6}`:

```
counts of a[i] mod k: {1,2,1,1,1}

products of distinct partitions of k:
  5   => 1
  4,1 => 2
  3,2 => 1

products of distinct partitions of 2 * k with parts <= k:
  5,4,1   => 2
  5,3,2   => 1
  4,1,3,2 => 2

products of distinct partitions of 3 * k with parts <= k:
  5,4,1,3,2 => 2

answer = 11

  {1,4} {4,6} {2,3} {5}
  {1,4,2,3} {1,4,5} {4,6,2,3} {4,6,5} {2,3,5}
  {1,4,2,3,5} {4,6,2,3,5}
```